# Volume control for Xamarin iOS using XamarinMediaManager nuget

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer, plugin.mediamanager.forms

When playing audio using XamarinMediaManager nuget on xamarin ios, the audio is very soft even though the volume is set to maximum. This nuget package works perfectly fine for android.

I have a global variable for the player set on page load:

```
        public IMediaManager NewPlayer { get; set; }
```

```
public AudioPage()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                NewPlayer = CrossMediaManager.Current;
                NewPlayer.MediaItemFinished += NewPlayer_MediaItemFinished;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "Ok");
            }
        }
```

When the screen loads, the audio file is loaded to the player:

```
 public async void SetAudioPlayer(string AudioPath)
        {
            try
            {

                if (File.Exists(AudioPath))
                {

                    if (NewPlayer.Queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        NewPlayer.Queue.Clear();
                    }

                    var generatedMediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.CreateMediaItem(AudioPath);
                    // Add media item to queue
                    NewPlayer.Queue.Add(generatedMediaItem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "Ok");
            }
        }
```

This is the code for when the play button is clicked:

```
private async void imgPlay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (NewPlayer.Queue.MediaItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                        await NewPlayer.PlayQueueItem(CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.MediaItems.Count - 1);
                    else
                        await NewPlayer.Play();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "Ok");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see a volume setting in that code? Maybe `NewPlayer.Volume = 1;`?

Comment: I have tried that with varying integers from 1-10 and it did not change the issue from above , thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've add good success (iOS, Android) with [Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer). On that, I had to set volume to 1 to get good volume.